# IOS, strange crash when app try to exit.

Tags: ios, crash

See the following crash got from apple app store, confused on the following questions.

1. When will app try to exit and crash in such call stack?
2. Which cases will cause app crash in this way?

Any discussion or suggestion  will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,3
Process:         ScoutFree [2276]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/BD0A91F2-DEA3-439C-B8A0-4CB695CEF735/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      ScoutFree
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-08-14 16:31:38.700 -0400
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xff6ca1f8
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ???                               0xff6ca1f8 0 + -9657864
1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x349534f8 exit
2   UIKit                             0x31746fe6 -[UIApplication _terminateWithStatus:]
3   UIKit                             0x3174389a -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:]
4   UIKit                             0x316d3efa -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:]
5   UIKit                             0x316d3562 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
6   UIKit                             0x316d2f36 _UIApplicationHandleEvent
7   GraphicsServices                  0x31347226 PurpleEventCallback
8   CoreFoundation                    0x30f8551e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
9   CoreFoundation                    0x30f854c0 __CFRunLoopDoSource1
10  CoreFoundation                    0x30f8430e __CFRunLoopRun + 1366
11  CoreFoundation                    0x30f074a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
12  CoreFoundation                    0x30f07368 CFRunLoopRunInMode
13  GraphicsServices                  0x31346434 GSEventRunModal
14  UIKit                             0x31701cd0 UIApplicationMain
15  ScoutFree                         0x000739f8 -[TelenavNavigatorAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (TelenavNavigatorAppDelegate.m:312)
16  ScoutFree                         0x00003384 0x00003384 (in MyApp)
```

Comment: have you seen any suspicious thing in this log...?

Comment: have you tried ZombieEnabled ?

Comment: What's happening in this part of the code: (TelenavNavigatorAppDelegate.m:312)?  It seems as if your app never returned from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, which seems odd to me.

Comment: Yes, very strange, why it will never return here? Any possible reason? I can't reproduce it locally.